# What's wrong with this MOD Rewrite Rule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
# Tags
RewriteRule   ^tags/(\d+)/$ /tags/view/index.cfm\?tagURL=$1 [L]
```

the tag can be anything. What's wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work, apache error.  I changed it to ^tags/(.*)/$ and it worked. is that safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only like to allow digits as tags, you can use this:

```
RewriteRule   ^tags/([0-9]+)/$ /tags/view/index.cfm\?tagURL=$1 [L]
```

Otherwiese, your solution

```
RewriteRule   ^tags/(.*)/$ /tags/view/index.cfm\?tagURL=$1 [L]
```

is perfectly fine.